# Null space equals annihilator of range of adjoint in general spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

(It turns out that the claim is incorrect as pointed out in the comment. Will get back soon)

Let $A, B$ be normed linear spaces and let $S$ be a bounded linear map from $A$ to $B$. Define the map $S^* : B^* \rightarrow A^*$ by $S^*(g)(v) = g(S(v))$ for $g \in B^*, v \in A$. It’s easy to see that $S^*$ is also a bounded linear map.

Prove that the kernel of $S$ is isomorphic to the annihiltor of the range of $S^*$, where the annihilator of a subspace $Y$ of a normed linear space $X$ is defined as $\{f \in X^* \mid f(a) = 0, \forall a \in Y \}.$

I tried search online but most of the results are for Hilbert spaces. I tried to build an isomorphism from the kernel to the annihilator of range of adjoint (which is a subspace of $A^{**}$) by sending $v$ to the evaluation at $v$. However, I am not able to show that this map is surjective, namely for any function $\in A^{**}$ that vanishes at the range of the adjoint, it must be the evaluation at some $v \in$ the kernel of $S$.

Thank you!

Comment: What you call "orthogonal complement" should better be called annihilator, and it comes in two versions: the one you describe and $Y_\perp=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=0\text{ for all }f\in Y\}$. You need to take this second version to make your claim true (and its not only an isomrophism, but equality).

Comment: @MaoWao Do you have a counterexample to the OP's claim?

Comment: @ThomasShelby Take the zero operator on $c_0$ (or any Banach space that is not isomorphic to its second dual).

Comment: @MaoWao thank you for the suggestion and pointing out the error. I will double check the question and get back. Sorry!

Comment: @MaoWao and for the version of annihilator you described, to show the annihilator of range of adjoint is a subset of the kernel, we use the result that functions in dual space separate points in the original space, right?

Comment: @ZhouChenliang Yes, exactly.

Comment: @MaoWao  thank you!